# Pull Manager Name From LDAP Query [ SQL View Created from LDAP Query ]

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory, ldap

I've setup this view:

```
SELECT     
displayname AS [Full Name], manager, department, company, 
physicaldeliveryofficename, mail AS [E-Mail Address], telephonenumber
FROM         
OPENQUERY(ADSI, 
'SELECT 
sAMAccountName, givenName, company, 
physicaldeliveryofficename, sn, displayname, mail, telephonenumber,department, useraccountcontrol, manager 
FROM 
''LDAP://DC=blah,DC=local''
WHERE 
objectClass = ''User'' and objectCategory = ''Person''') AS derivedtbl_1
WHERE     
(useraccountcontrol & 2 = 0)
```

pulling employee data from ActiveDirectory using SQL Server however the manager field comes with all the mappings: CN, OU, DC and looks like this:

CN=blah blah,OU= blah ,OU=blah TGP,DC= blah,DC=local

whereas all I really want is their full name (CN.)

I'd like two things:

1. To pull just the CN from the view.
2. Get the manager's email.

The view uses the following fields:

displayname, manager, department, company, physicaldeliveryofficename, mail

However I'd like the end result to have the additional field Manager Email at the end of the it to complete the full dataset.

As mentioned the view with all of the information has been successfully created and therefore this can be done on the SQL side but I'm struggling to find a method to achieve what I want.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Added View Code

Answer (score 0):

Old question but for anyone else who is looking for a solution. pulled the CN via some SUBSTRING work. The SUBSTRING will grab anything between the first equals sign and the first comma, solves the first issue:

```
SELECT       [displayname] AS [Full Name], 
         [manager], 
         LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([manager], CHARINDEX('=', [manager]) + 1, CHARINDEX(',', [manager]) - CHARINDEX('=', [manager]) - 1))) AS [ManagerName], 
         [department], 
         [company], 
         [physicaldeliveryofficename], 
         [mail] AS [E-Mail Address], 
         [telephonenumber]
   FROM  OPENQUERY([ADSI], 'SELECT sAMAccountName, givenName, company, physicaldeliveryofficename, sn, displayname, mail, telephonenumber,department, useraccountcontrol, manager FROM ''LDAP://DC=blah,DC=local'' WHERE objectClass = ''User'' and objectCategory = ''Person''') AS [derivedtbl_1]
   WHERE [useraccountcontrol]&2 = 0;
```